# Create NSItemProvider from NSImage

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage, nsitemprovider

#### Question:

- How to create `NSItemProvider` from `NSImage`? The image is not being shown in `LPLinkView`
- Is there any other alternate way for creating an `NSItemProvider` from an image on macOS?

#### My failed attempt:

Even though I managed to create the object the `LPLinkView` doesn't display the image

```
let image1 = NSImage(named: "Car")!
let itemProvider1 = NSItemProvider(item: image1, typeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier)
```

Comment: Where would you use a `NSItemProvider` object in Cocoa?  What is the iOS tag for?

Comment: It is used in share extensions and drag and drop. UTType is not an iOS tag, it is Uniform Type (identifier)

Comment: I didn't ask what `UTType` is.  You have the iOS tag.

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks, updated tag, can you please remove the close tag.